# JMS message not getting added

Tags: jms, hornetq, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am facing a strange situation while using HornetQ.

My application architecture -

- JMS provider : HornetQ (Standalone server, not used for anything else. I've created 2 queues on this server, say Q1 and Q2).
- Producer : A web application deployed on a separate machine. This application creates instances of "ObjectMessage", passing a "Job" class instance as argument to the "ObjectMessage.setObject()" method and adds the message to Q1. Uses Spring JMS.

I also set a string property named "AGENT" in the message before adding it to the queue.

What's peculiar is that if I call ObjectMessage.setStringProperty("AGENT", null) or if I do not add the property to the message itself, the message does not get added to Q1. However, this does not happen on Q2, and I'm able to see the message in HornetQ's JMX console.

Is there some queue specific configuration that I should be looking out for?

Apologies for the loose wording - My team and I have been facing a tough time trying to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the Producer? and How are you sending it?

It seems you're not committing on a transactional session?

I'm assuming you are using JMS, but I would need to see some code to help you in a better fashion. Usually the JBoss Forum is a better suitable place for discussions like this, since the SOF is not really a discussion forum.

I think the best would be you open a forum on JBoss (since it will be followed by a discussion) and provide the link here.

Comment: Clebert, this issue was resolved by our team a few days ago. The problem was that the piece of code that was sending a message to the queue was being accessed by multiple threads at the same time. Fixing the code to make it thread-safe fixed the problem. We're still trying to investigate what was the root cause. Thanks anyways.